# Why android video data from MediaRecorder connected with DatagramSocket are not sended instantly?

Tags: android, udp, android-mediarecorder

I'm writing an Android application which creates MediaRecorder set output file with

```
final ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromDatagramSocket(socket);
```

socket is DatagramSocket. I can start recorder, but it only sends this (or server receives this)

```
server got: ftypisomisom3gp4 from 192.168.1.12:51433
server got:  from 192.168.1.12:51433
```

after DatagramSocket is closed, it sends another few messages, which can be probably video. Does anybody know why DatagramSocket doesn't send video instantly?

Before this implementation I used standard TCP socket and everything works fine (excepts for latency).

On server is running Nodejs. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: define 'instantly'. (probably lacks a flush of some kind at some point)

Comment: Instantly - after MediaRecorder starts. I cant write any flush, its matter of MediaRecorder, isnt it?

Comment: Please somebody explain to him what is the difference with UDP and TCP and why isn't good the UDP for Real time transfer, I have tryed, but no success